# VBA Calculate row with Formulas and paste answers as Values in another row

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Now I am using the bellow code to generate all dates by hours between given date range. And after that there are formulas in Row 16 which are copied to Row 18 and then each formula is auto-filled down till the last date in column А. The date is used in the formulas. Тhe code is working fine but it is working very slow to calculate and update all formulas at once. I suppose that the problem is because each cell after row 17 is a formula. So now I am wondering is there a way to edit the code to calculate each formula in row 16 by each time interval and the result to be copied as a value from row 18 down to the last row with date in column A.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()
'Updated on 02-10-2017
Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.StatusBar = "Getting Daily Results...."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Rows(18 & ":" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents
Rows("16:16").Copy Destination:=Rows("18:18")
Range("A18", Range("A18").End(xlDown)).Clear
Dim rng As Range
Dim StartRng As Range
Dim EndRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim IntvlHrsRng As Range
Dim IntvlHrs As Long
Dim StartValue As Variant
Dim EndValue As Variant
Const xTitleId As String = "KutoolsforExcel"
Dim ColIndex As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ic As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowDB As Long
Set StartRng = Application.Selection
Set StartRng = Range("B3")
Set EndRng = Range("B4")
Set IntvlHrsRng = Range("B5")
Set OutRng = Range("A18")
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")
StartValue = StartRng.Range("A1").Value
EndValue = EndRng.Range("A1").Value
IntvlHrs = IntvlHrsRng.Range("A1").Value
    If IntvlHrs = 0 Then IntvlHrs = 24

If EndValue - StartValue <= 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    ColIndex = 0

    For I = StartValue * 24 To EndValue * 24 Step IntvlHrs
        OutRng.Offset(ColIndex, 0) = I / 24
        OutRng.Offset(ColIndex, 0).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
        ColIndex = ColIndex + 1
    Next I

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowDB = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If LastRowDB >= LastRow Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

For ic = 2 To 99

    Cells(LastRowDB, ic).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LastRowDB, ic), Cells(LastRow, ic))

Next ic

ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Application.StatusBar = "Ready"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```